# Typhoon: How to get an instance conforming to a protocol for production, and another for tests?

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

I've defined an ApplicationAssembly in Typhoon.

So what I want to do is say: "This class X needs to be injected with something conforming to the Foo protocol. This is a RealFoo, this is a TestFoo. When I'm running X in real life, I want it to get a RealFoo, but when I'm running my integration tests, I want it to get a TestFoo".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several recommended ways to do this:

**Use the Typhoon Patcher**

[Typhoon-patcher](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_patcher.html) allows loading a base assembly, but with one or more components patched out with another definition, or a given object instance. Here's an example of patching out a component with a mock:

```
MiddleAgesAssembly* assembly = [MiddleAgesAssembly assembly];
TyphoonComponentFactory* factory = [TyphoonBlockComponentFactory factoryWithAssembly:assembly];

TyphoonPatcher* patcher = [[TyphoonPatcher alloc] init];
[patcher patchDefinition:[assembly knight] withObject:^id
{
    Knight* mockKnight = mock([Knight class]);
    [given([mockKnight favoriteDamsels]) willReturn:@[
        @"Mary",
        @"Janezzz"
    ]];

    return mockKnight;
}];

[factory attachPostProcessor:patcher];

Knight* knight = [factory componentForKey:@"knight"];
```

**Group Environment Dependent Components Together**

Another approach is to group environment dependent components together. If you're using the XML style assembly, you can load a different set of files for production vs test scenarios, including the base assembly and any environment dependent files.

The same thing can be achieved in the block-based assembly, as follows:

```
TyphoonComponentFactory* factory = [[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory alloc] initWithAssemblies:@[
    [MiddleAgesAssembly assembly],
    [StarWarsAssembly assembly]
]];

Knight* cavalryMan = [(MiddleAgesAssembly*) factory cavalryMan];
Knight* stormTrooper = [(StarWarsAssembly*) factory stormTrooper];
```

For more information consult ***Modularization of Assemblies*** in the [Typhoon documentation](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Assembling-components-with-blocks), or check out the [sample app](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example), which contains an example of this.

**Use a TyphoonConfig**

Another approach is to use TyphoonConfig. Details for this feature are [here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-configuration).

**Edit:**

The above example is for Typhoon 2.0. This still works fine with Typhoon 3.0, but somewhat neater is assembly activation:

```
MiddleAgesAssembly *assembly = [[MiddleAgesAssembly new] activate]; 
Knight *knight = [assembly knight];
```

- In Typhoon 3.0 you only need to declare collaborating assemblies if they are backed by a protocol not a concrete type, or if you wish to override one of your assemblies.
- You can resolve components from the collaborating assemblies with eg`[assembly.colloaboratingAssembly stormTrooper]`

Comment: Hi Jasper I'm taking a look at your framework. Being a DI newbie, I think I would benefit on the Github page (https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon) if you could include a small example of weatherClient injection using the framework. I was expecting a tah-dah moment after all that long introduction. Although it is explained in the Github wikipages how to use the framework. As a newcomer I find the mental link between the manual case and the Typhoon case lacking.

Comment: Also about the advantage of using a DI framework, yes I understand that I don't want to program without the compiler. However, I still do not necessarily understand the benefit of using a framework. I think the insight may come after I've manually use them for a while. Right now, I can think of one reason I might want to use some abstraction: it is that with DI I'm basically exposing what otherwise would be hidden in the class that require dependency and I do not like it.

Comment: At the moment the framework is aimed at users who've used DI in other languages and understand the benefits - the docs are quite thin. . however we're planning on a book. . in the meantime perhaps checkout a) The Manning 'Dependency Injection' book b) This StackExchange question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200796/how-is-dependency-injection-not-just-moving-the-complexity-into-a-separate-class c) The sample app. . DI doesn't expose parts of your class that are supposed to be hidden, it promotes a clear contract between the *main collaborators*

Comment: @huggie In a nutshell, think of it as putting some "rails" around the assembly of your application from its constituent parts. (Excuse the pun ;) )

Comment: Well, what I mean by hidden is exactly this object that gets injected is now needed to be, uh, injected; whereas without DI which object it really uses is part of the implementation detail the user doesn't need to care about. And wow a book! Now I see this really isn't a 5 cent concept. (http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html)