# Typhoon: How is patching a definition related to component keys?

Tags: typhoon

I'm trying to implement a patcher as demonstrated in the documentation and this SO post: [Typhoon: How to get an instance conforming to a protocol for production, and another for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838570/typhoon-how-to-get-an-instance-conforming-to-a-protocol-for-production-and-ano).

I'm using block assembly and get the error:

```
[WPAnalyticsClientImplementation key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9eb01d0
```

at `TyphoonPatcher.m: 46`.

My class implementation does not respond to this selector. Should it? How are keys related to the patching process?

```
context(@"when the controller does something", ^{

        it(@"should work", ^{
            // This is an application test, so the factory has already been set in the app delegate.
            TyphoonComponentFactory *factory = [TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory];

            TyphoonPatcher* patcher = [[TyphoonPatcher alloc] init];
            [patcher patchDefinition:[factory componentForType:@protocol(WPAnalyticsClient)] withObject:^id
             {
                 id mockAnalytics = [KWMock mockForProtocol:@protocol(WPAnalyticsClient)];
                 [[mockAnalytics should] conformToProtocol:@protocol(WPAnalyticsClient)];
                 [mockAnalytics stub:@selector(getSomeString) andReturn:theValue(@"fake implementation")];

                 return mockAnalytics;
             }];

            [factory attachPostProcessor:patcher];

            // The default factory should now return the mocked client.
            id <WPAnalyticsClient> client = [factory componentForType:@protocol(WPAnalyticsClient)];

            NSLog(@"conforms: %i", [client conformsToProtocol:@protocol(WPAnalyticsClient)]);
            NSString *actualValue = [client getSomeString];
            NSLog(@"someString: %@", actualValue);
            [[theValue([actualValue isEqualToString:@"fake implementation"]) should] equal:theValue(YES)];
        });
    });
```

AppDelegate.m

```
TyphoonComponentFactory *factory = ([[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory alloc] initWithAssembly:[WPAssembly assembly]]);
[factory makeDefault];
```

Comment: No, you don't have to change any code or respond to a selector in your class. Something else has gone wrong. . . can you post your patching code/test-cast ?

Comment: Sure I'll update my question. I think my problem comes from the fact that I'm trying to patch an already existing factory as opposed to a new one as in the example.

We're using an application test so theoretically by the time the test runs an existing assembly/factory should have been created by the app delegate?

Comment: So sorry . . . I gave you the wrong advise earlier. I instructed to cast the TyphoonComponentFactory to the Assembly type. . normally you can do this, but in the case of the patcher, you don't. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patching code shown above is not quite right, rather than patch an ***instance***, you patch a ***definition***.

The way the patcher works is to use a TyphoonComponentFactoryPostProcessor to mutate a definition.

So rather than doing this:

```
[patcher patchDefinition:[factory componentForType:@protocol(WPAnalyticsClient)] 
    withObject:^id. . .
```

You should do this:

```
MyAssemblyType* assembly = [MyAssemblyType assembly];
TyphoonComponentFactory* factory = [TyphoonBlockComponentFactory factoryWithAssembly:assembly];   
[patcher patchDefinition:[assembly myComponentToPatch] withObject . . . ];
```

**Patching the Default Assembly::**

Because you're patching the default assembly, rather than creating a new one, you have to pass in the definition as follows:

```
[patcher patchDefinition:[[MyAssemblyType assembly] myAnalticsService] withObject. . . ]
```

**Component Keys vs Assembly Interface**

Let's say you have a component as follows:

```
- (id) myAnalyticsService 
{
    return [TyphoonDefinitionWithClass. . . . etc]; 
}
```

. . . then the key of your component is *@"myAnalyticsService"* so you could also use:

```
[patcher patchDefinitionWithKey:@"myAnalyticsService" . . ];
```

**Assembly Interface at Build-time vs Runtime**

Here's a concept that could cause some confusion:

The assembly interface serves two purposes. At build-time it returns TyphoonDefinition, while at runtime it returns the actual type defined in the definition. So . .

- At build time we can define components.
- At run-time we can resolve components using the method name on the assembly interface

Example:

```
MyAssemblyType* assembly = (MyAssemblyType*) [TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory];
//Use the assembly interface instead of a 'magic string'
AnalyticsService* service = [assembly analyticsService];
```

This is a lot of information . . . let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think on second thoughts you may be right that an alternative "test" assembly may be a better approach.

If I made a new assembly in my test though, how would I make this the default factory? Given that the production assembly has already been set as the default in AppDelegate.m?

I tried using [factory makeDefault] but this uses dispatch_once. Is the suggested technique to use the preprocessor and a testing flag to control which assembly is allocated? This would work but would mean I have to include all my test code/libraries in my main project :/.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. The example code posted is a simplified example of a certain problem I  was having.

(Unfortunately!) we're using storyboards which is making testing a little tricky in places. In our ViewController's initWithCoder: method we ask the default factory for the controller's dependencies.

In our controller integration test we then create an alternative test assembly, that provides kiwi mocks. Once this is set as the default factory, we can instantiate the storyboard and controller in our test.

Comment: Hopefully when initWithCoder: is called on the controller under test, the mock versions of its dependencies will be supplied. We've also set the test assembly to always use singleton scope with all its definitions so that we can set stubs/expectations on objects from the DI container and the same instances are then returned in the controller's initWithCoder: method. It seems to be working, no idea if this is the best way to do it though! Many thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: The line `[patcher patchDefinition:[assembly myComponentToPatch] withObject . . . ];` won't type-check. Did you miss out a cast?